# Prove there exists $a \in E$ such that $a = f(a)$, assuming $d(f(x), f(y)) \le Kd(x,y)$ with $K<1$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: E \rightarrow E$, $E$ a complete metric space. Assume that there exists $K$ such that $0 < K < 1$ and $d(f(x), f(y)) \le Kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in E$. Prove that there exists $a \in E$ such that $a=f(a)$.

This was a problem given to me by a friend, as I am self studying real analysis. I am unsure of how to proceed with this question. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Please: Look at my edits.  Your way of writing MathJax code is not correct.  You shouldn't keep alternating in and out of MathJax in a single expression, and if you write something like $A$<$B$ instead of $A<B$, you get font mismatches and lack of proper spacing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question on Complete Metric Spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638972/question-on-complete-metric-spaces)

Comment: It has to be $d(f(x), f(y)) \le Kd(x,y)$ not $<$. Otherwise no map can satisfy the inequality for $x=y$.

Answer (score 3):

Try to prove that $x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))),\ldots$ is a Cauchy sequence.  Let $a$ be its limit.  Then see if you can show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, $d(a,f(a))<\varepsilon$.

A function $f$ for which there exists $K$ between $0$ and $1$ such that for all points $x,y$ one has $d(f(x),f(y))\le Kd(x,y)$ is called a contraction.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I haven't taken real analysis, but doesn't this definition of contraction imply $d(f(a),f(a))<Kd(a,a)\implies0<0$? oops and he just edited it so that it's less than or equal to. Never mind

Comment: Sorry -- I've changed it to $\le$.  One can get by with $<$ as long as $x\ne y$. But just saying $\le$ is enough and is simpler than making that exception. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: +1. While sufficient for the conclusion, is completeness also *necessary*?

Comment: @KimJongUn : It is necessary.  Consider for example the contraction $x\mapsto x/2$ on the space $(0,\infty)$.  It has no fixed point.  The Cauchy sequence $(1/2^n)_{n=0}^\infty$ in that space does not converge. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Some contractions of metric spaces that are not complete do have fixed points: for example the contraction $x\mapsto x/2$ on the rationals.  If one replaced the hypothesis that every Cauchy sequence converges to the hypothesis that the sequence $x, f(x), f(f(x)),\ldots$ converges, one would lose something: in some applications the existence of the limit is the very thing one wants to prove.  For example, the Picard theorem on existence of solutions of differential equations.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks.